# Inserting a Nav Bar with Rollover effects

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

For those of you who have heard this question already.

If you were to go ahead and try to make a Navigation Bar what would be your first step.  Would you use the Photoshop "Rollover" method?  Or would you hand code it (so to speak).

Right now I have a Navigation Bar ready to export into Dreameaver cs5.  I cannot seem to have the "hover" effect to, well, hover.  I proceed to publish my entire site.  My navigation bar is at the top of my web page but I still cannot seem to have any sort of link animation happening.  When I go ahead and open a new html document and just throw it into the header it works fine with a blank html document.  Why is it that my specific index.html document does not want to "have" my navigation bar or have it work correctly.

I know I'm going to be terribly scorned for my lack of knowledge even asking this question.

Please any help would be appreciated.  It seems I cannot post any images yet..I would if I could.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site about writing code, so Photoshop/Dreamweaver stuff is off-topic. But yes, you can easily do rollover effects in code using css's `:hover`

Comment: If you're site \ staging area is online - share a link (comment \ update the question) and I'll be happy to take a look. If it's not, maybe share some code so we can see what's going on behind the scene. Coding a hover effect is a simple task if you're familiar with some Javascript (or even CSS). If you can add more info on your nav-bar I'll be happy to show you how.

Comment: When you ask something on StackOverflow, you should always show your current code, what isn't working, what you've tried and what you want to happen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/IntriguedArtist/T9tW8/

Comment: I know I probably have it completely set up wrong but I'm trying to get all of the NavBar_01, NavBar_02, etc... into the source code.  My question,  Is there a bit more work that needs to go into it?  I'm sure there is...I'm just asking point me in that direction I need to go to the proper 1st step.

Comment: Maybe you can try to check out this tutorial
http://www.entheosweb.com/photoshop/navigation_bar.asp